# How big a custom corpora should be

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I'm planning on building my own custom corpora based on phrases that are relevant to my specific real world needs. it will be tagged and chunked.
My question is: how big the corpus should be and what are the best practices when building one.
I'm guessing people use nltk for many different businesses domains, when it would it a good choice to use the internal nltk tagger and not a custom one?